# How do I read different schema json objects from a single file and save it to a table

Tags: json, pyspark

I am new to pyspark. Can please help me with creating a table from json file using pyspark. It had set of 2 diff objects, need to combined as a single row based on id.

sample json file data:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "UP1981",
    "price1": "$49.99",
    "platforms": [
      "PS4"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "UP1981",
    "title": "HOT WHEELS",
  },
  {
    "id": "UP1982",
    "price1": "$50",
    "platforms": [
      "PS4"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "UP1982",
    "title": "HOT WHEELS2",
  }
]
```

output table: 4 columns - `id`, `price1`, `platforms`, `title`:

```
|   id      |  price1    |   Platforms  |   title          | 
|   UP1981   |  $49.99   |   PS4        |   HOT WHEELS     |
|   UP1982   |   $50     |   PS4        |   HOT WHEELS2    |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the json file using **`spark.read.json`** then by grouping the data by id and apply aggregations on top of the data.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df=spark.read.option("multiLine",True).json("<json_file_path>")

df.groupBy("id").agg(array_join(first("platforms"),"").alias("platforms"),first("price1").alias("price1"),max("title").alias("title")).show()
#+------+---------+------+-----------+
#|    id|platforms|price1|      title|
#+------+---------+------+-----------+
#|UP1981|      PS4|$49.99| HOT WHEELS|
#|UP1982|      PS4|   $50|HOT WHEELS2|
#+------+---------+------+-----------+
```